# How to calculate the value of two edittexts without a button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to android studio. I'm working on a simple project, where the user puts two inputs in two edittext fields. There is a calculation to be made with those inputs, and i need the tesult to be shown automaticaly in another text view, without making the user click a button. How can i do that?

Comment: I think you just have to add a "addTextChangedListener" listener and update the value of your third edittextfield when the user writes something in the others edittextfields..

Answer (score 1):

for this purpose, you can use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) and listen for text changes on edittexts

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {


             // do whatever you want
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```